# How do I stop PuTTY becoming unresponsive to input when displaying large amounts of text?

Tags: ssh, putty

I use a windows 7 machine to `ssh` into a remote Linux machine using `PuTTY 0.62`. When I accidentally forget to stream the output to a file and run a program that prints a lot of data to the screen I find that putty becomes unresponsive to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and I just have to wait 5 minutes before my keystroke to be registered.

Is there any way to limit the incoming data rate so I can still send keystrokes to the remote machine in the event that I get myself in this situation again?

I should add that it's not really `PuTTY` *per se* becoming unresponsive, but it's just not sending keystrokes, presumably because network throughput is being gobbled up by millions of lines of text being displayed on the screen.

I am using `tmux`, and the session is equally slow to respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> as to any other command.

Comment: Even if the solution involves the unix end, you'd have to interact through PuTTY to trigger it.

Comment: What if I could reduce the maximum rate at which lines are printed to the terminal?

Comment: You could do that, yes, but you'd have to do it in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a router that allows you to provide traffic shaping, you could set the inbound SSH traffic rate (port 22 or whatever port you're using for the remote host) to be something slightly less than the max line rate on your windows 7 host.  That way, your putty session will be able to shove <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or other commands) into the remote host.

I'm not sure how to do traffic shaping or QoS on windows 7, but I'm sure there are apps that will allow you to accomplish something similar on your host.

Finally, you can use <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd> to escape the session, and then send a <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> (send break) but I'm not sure if that will help your problem... worth a shot.  Please let us know if it works!